# Server / cashier / waiter

Tags: alternatives

I am writing a document where a person is serving the guests and takes their payments. I need one word to be consistently used across the document. For now I used a server. Is it appropriate? I am still wondering about cashier or waiter alternatives. What would native speaker pick up?

Comment: **Server** would puzzle most people. **Waiters** both serve diners and take payments, depending on the way the restaurant is organised. Large, posher restaurants may well employ a **maître d** but that's more for purposes of control.  For your purposes I suggest you stick with **waiter**

Comment: @RonaldSole At least in the service industry around Toronto, *server* is the word that the staff use when referring to themselves. It's what I always use—mainly because I know *they* don't use *waiter*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most appropriate would be waiter.

A cashier is someone who mans the register, takes payments and issues the receipts, but that is not used in the context of a typical restaurant or diner unless you have to go to a counter to pay for the food yourself.

Most native speakers would get what you mean by server, but if removed from the context, they might think of a different meaning for it, so just go with waiter.